# Micro SD card doesn't boot on Zero, but works on Pi3

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-zero, boot-issues

So I've got this 32GB micro SD card, with Jessie Lite installed on it.
It won't boot on any of my Raspberry Pi Zero W's or Zero, but its just fine on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Literally nothing happens when I plug any of my Pi Zero's into power with the SD card inserted. However the same SD card does work in my Raspberry Pi 3. It's a fresh install.

Anyone an idea what causes this behaviour?

Comment: How about giving some details of what actually happens?

Comment: have you tried the zero first or the pi 3? Because that could be it.

Comment: I frequently move raspbian lite jessie cards between Zeros and 3Bs without issue, so it *can* work. The question in this case is what has been done to make it *not* work. Please provide more detail.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with Raspberry Pi Zero W. The problem is with the Micro SD card make / manufacturer. Better to use SanDisk.