# PI Zero will not boot, Pi 3 will same sd card

Tags: boot, sd-card, pi-zero, boot-issues, bootloader

I have a Pi 3 and a Pi Zero. I have a sandisk sd card a no name sd card. My Pi 3 will boot with both sd cards. The Pi zero will only boot with the sandisk. I am using the same latest image on both cards. The Pi Zero performed as if there was no sd card ( no LED activity)

I have tried:

- multiple no name sd cards formatted re imaged, all using win32 disk
  imager
- performed sudo update, upgrade, dis-update and rpi-update
- copied the boot from one to the other.
- Attempted with RISCOS
- Attempted NOOBS v 2.4.4
- Attempted Stretch light

After placing the old SD card into the pi zero for about 5 min I pulled it out to check the logs. I see not update in any logs from /var/log/

- Pi zero 1.3
- SD card 8gb class 10
- Sam power used for Pi3 and Pi zero

Why would the Pi zero be sd card sensitive? any other troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Related? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67691/micro-sd-card-doesnt-boot-on-zero-but-works-on-pi3

Comment: Possibly, I looked but it and no answers. I do not have rep high enough to post a comment.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if I remember right a ARMv8 (Raspberry Pi 3) kernel can't run on a ARMv6 (Zero). To check the running kernel version, submit the command `uname -a` in a terminal.

Comment: Thank you, if this was the case the the Sandisk card would not work in the pi zero. I must trying to identify if there is a possible hardware limitation?
I have tried using the same boot partition on both sd cards as well. Tried to exspand the system before placing it on the pi zero, and still no luck.

Comment: and you checked the kernel version?

Comment: uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SNP ... armv7l gnu/Linux